# How to find given by the points $(x_0,y_0)=(0.8,2.1)$ first two steps of Newton's method?

Tags: calculus

How to find given by the points $(x_0,y_0)=(0.8,2.1)$ first two steps of Newton's method ,in order to approximate for $f(x,y)=x^3+14x+x^2y^2-5y$ one result of system of equation $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$?

What is what I have found:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2+14+2xy^2$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2x^2y−5$$

Let $g(x,y)=3x^2+14+2xy^2$ and $h(x,y)=2x^2y−5$.

I construct the Jacobian $J(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\\ 
 \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}
\end{pmatrix}$.

I'm not sure if this was helpful but what next should I do?

Comment: What **is** 'Newton's method' for two variables?

Comment: I wouldn't be here If I knew @user247327

Comment: @MissJune Here's an excellent discussion. http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat419/lecture9.pdf You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

So you got a matrix that looks like this:$$\begin{pmatrix}6x+2y^2&4xy\\4xy&2x^2\end{pmatrix}$$
Let $(x_0,y_0)=(1,2)$, which is very close to $(0.8,2.1)$, plug in and get$$\begin{pmatrix}14&8\\8&2\end{pmatrix}$$
The linearization equation is $$L_f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}f_x(x_0,y_0)\\f_y(x_0,y_0)\end{pmatrix}+J_f(x_0,y_0)\begin{pmatrix}x-x_0\\y-y_0\end{pmatrix}$$
So it is $$L_f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}25\\-1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}14&8\\8&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0.8-1\\2.1-2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What about second step? I got $\begin{pmatrix}23\\ -2.4\end{pmatrix}$. Should I put this values again instead of $f_x$ and $f_y$?

Comment: Why you used values 2 and 1. To make easier calculation or? I dont understand..